# How to get hexadecimal values DX and AX from an IMUL?

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, hex

What will be the hexadecimal values of DX and AX after the following instructions have executed?

```
mov dx,-32
mov ax,4
imul dx
```

`-128 = 128 = 2^7= 1000 0000 = 0000 0000 1000 0000`

2's compliment to turn the positive number into a negative

`1111 1111 1000 0000`

I'm confused on how to get the hexidecimal values for Dx and Ax from that number. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `imul` instruction does *signed* multiplication of `AX` and `DX`, placing the 32-bit result in the `DX:AX` register pair.  So the result is -128 as you say or `10000000` binary.

The 1's complement as a 32-bit result is `01111111` with 24 leading 1's.  Adding 1, we have 25 ones followed by 7 zeros.

So again this agrees with what you've done except you're not showing the leading 16 bits, which are all ones.

The result has the high order 16 bits in `DX` and low order in `AX`.  So you have

```
DX = 0xFFFF and AX = 0xFF80
```

Comment: where i'm confused is where do you get the `0xFFFF` and 0xFF80`? Or should i say how do you get them

Answer (score 0):

Since the `imul` you used is producing a 32 bit signed result, you should have used 32 bit arithmetic. As such, the full value is `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000`. The top 16 bits go into `DX` the low 16 into `AX`. I trust you have no problem converting from binary to hex: the value of `DX` is `0xFFFF` and `AX` is `0xFF80`.